# Listen for TCP connection from connected object on 3G network

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I have a connected object that works on 3G network and that is sending data to my IP on a selectable port.

I would like to read the data sent from this object on a node.js program because all my API on my server is on node.js

For this I tried to create a 'net' server like this :

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    socket.on('data', function (data) {

        var StrData = data.toString('ascii');
        fs.appendFile("test.txt","data received : "+ StrData, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(StrData);
        });
    });
});
server.listen(2000, '0.0.0.0');
```

And I am getting all the data sent by the object to my "test.txt" file as wanted. The problem is that it seems that the connection is closed by my server after receiving the first data, so my connected object have to create another connection every time and just can send the first data.

My question is:

How can I let the connection opened so the object can send all the data?

I also tried 'socket.io' and 'http' but I can't get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug the issue with the given code, can you try to add an error listener to your socket and see if any errors are triggered:

```
socket.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
}
```

My guess is your client is closing the socket, thinking the request is timed out (since you are not returning a success response of some sort). `net.createServer` creates a TCP server which expects a response for all requests.

Comment: Even when I answer something, It doesn't work :( It seems like the connection closed automatically after receiving a packet, actually when I try the "nc" linux command to conenct to this ports, the conenction is closing after sending data when other server keep listening..